# How to make port 80 available? Installing xampp 1.7.7 on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, xampp, port

I'm trying to install/run xampp on windows 7 but it is failing because it says port 80 is in use.  I've turned off IIS but it's still showing that port 80 is in use by a "NT Kernal & System" process. See picture.

I'm not sure what to do.  I don't think I have permission to kill this system process plus it's probably a bad idea since it's related to the Kernal.
   This is driving me crazy.  Anyone else seeing this problem?

> [image]

Window 7 Enterprise, 64 bit os.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also look for, and turn off, "Web Deployment Agent Service". Did the trick for me.

Comment: What I ended up doing was simply switching apache to listen on a different port.  This answer would probably help others though.

Comment: Old thread I know but this answer worked for me so I was just wondering - what exactly does the Web Deployment Agent Service do?

Comment: You can find "Web Deployment Agent Service" in Start > Run > services.msc

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to your Windows Services `Start > Run > services.msc`
2. See if there is a `World Wide Publishing` service, `right-click` it to get the Properties
3. Click `Stop` if it is running...

Check this link: [Apachefirends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=194635&sid=29999bdc1ee1eab417f32e651bba2486)

Comment: also disable it or at least change the "autorun" option.

Answer (score 2):

A service called "Web Deployment Agant Service" was listening on port 80 , stopping and sdisabling that got me working...

Answer (score 1):

I found what my problem was....
Since im also developing Asp.net applications, web Deployment Agent Service was what had reserved the port.

So i went to services and Disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off, "Web Deployment Agent Service". Did the trick for me. Now XAMPP 1.7.7 works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed any other servers like MS-SQL, check for the services for that. Possibly stop the services relating to other servers. Worked for me.